# How to filter Powershell to compare directory name against AD SamAccountName and ignoring the .Vx pattern?

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting, active-directory, windows-scripting

My AD user account is in the format like **First.Last** name (SamAccountName).
The user HomeDirectory roaming profile is somehow got additional versioning like below:

```
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User10.Name.V1
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User28.Name.V2
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User6.Name.V3
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User3.Name.V3.old
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User23.Name.V6
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User81.Name.V8.OLD
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User61.Name.V9
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User73.Name.V12
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User33.Name.V5
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\User74.Name.V2
\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\First.LastName.RENAME
```

How to modify the Powershell script below to get only the **First.Last** name (SamAccountName) pattern from the list of directories above?

```
$ServerHomeDirShare = "\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\"
$filter = "(Enabled -eq 'true')"

# get all user accounts from AD; only SamAccountName required
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

# foreach directory in \\server\share check if it has a corresponding ad user
Get-ChildItem -Path $ServerHomeDirShare -Directory |
Select-Object -Property `
              Name,
              @{ n = 'AD User Exist'; e = { $users -contains $_.Name } },
              FullName,
              @{ n = 'LastAccessTime'; e = { $_.LastAccessTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') } },
              @{ n = "Directory Size (MB)"; e = {
                    Try
                    {
                        $Path = $_.FullName
                        $Size = ((Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -ErrorAction Stop).Length).Sum/1MB
                        [math]::Round($Size, 2)
                    }
                    Catch
                    {
                        "ERROR: $($_.Exception.Message)"
                    }
                }} |
Where-Object { -not $_.'AD User Exist' } |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\UserProfilesNotExist-Size.csv
```

So it can be compared against the AD database for separating the orphaned Home Directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex `-replace` on the directory name to get only the `Firstname.Lastname` part, skipping the `.Vx` and `.RENAME` (or `.WhatEver`)

Next, for your calculation of the directory size, I presume you want the total size, including the stuff inside subfolders, so I would change that method too:

```
$ServerHomeDirShare = '\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$'
$filter = "(Enabled -eq 'true')"

# get all user accounts from AD; only SamAccountName required
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

# foreach directory in \\server\share check if it has a corresponding ad user
# user SamAccountNames are in format 'FirstName.Lastname', so we need to cut off
# any versioning postfixex from the directory names in order to compare
Get-ChildItem -Path $ServerHomeDirShare -Directory |
Select-Object -Property Name,
              @{ n = 'AD User Exist'; e = { $users -contains ($_.Name -replace '^(\w+\.\w+).*', '$1') } },
              FullName,
              @{ n = 'LastAccessTime'; e = { $_.LastAccessTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') } },
              @{ n = "Directory Size (MB)"; e = {
                        Try {
                            $Size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
                                     Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB
                            [math]::Round($Size, 2)
                        }
                        Catch {
                            "ERROR: $($_.Exception.Message)"
                        }
                    }
                } |
Where-Object { -not $_.'AD User Exist' } |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\UserProfilesNotExist-Size.csv
```

Another approach could be to filter for only directories whose name cannot be found in the $users array straight away instead of afterwards.
In that case, you wouldn't need the column 'AD User Exist' because you know these are orphaned user folders.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $ServerHomeDirShare -Directory | 
Where-Object { $users -notcontains ($_.Name -replace '^(\w+\.\w+).*', '$1') } |
Select-Object -Property Name, FullName,
              @{ n = 'LastAccessTime'; e = { $_.LastAccessTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') } },
              @{ n = "Directory Size (MB)"; e = {
                        Try {
                            $Size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
                                     Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB
                            [math]::Round($Size, 2)
                        }
                        Catch {
                            "ERROR: $($_.Exception.Message)"
                        }
                    }
                } |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\UserProfilesNotExist-Size.csv
```

Regex details

```
^                Assert position at the beginning of the string
(                Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w            Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \.            Match the character “.” literally
   \w            Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)               
.                Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: thank you for the update. Somehow I got this in the size column: 
ERROR: Access to the path '\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\Stevanie.Angel.V6' is denied.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer That can always happen. You need to have permission to read everything in the (ex) user folders. In some cases, you need to take ownership and give yourself full control on the folder and all its files and subdirs, but that's another question.. Luckily, here are many examples on that to be found.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense.
This is the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409598/add-domain-domain-admins-group-as-full-access-to-the-orphaned-home-directory