# Add DOMAIN\Domain Admins group as Full Access to the orphaned Home Directory?

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting, active-directory, windows-scripting

The below script was created by the great https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo to list all orphaned HomeDirectory:

```
$ServerHomeDirShare = "\\FileServer\HomeDir$"
$filter = "(Enabled -eq 'true')"

# get all user accounts from AD; only SamAccountName required
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    Get-ChildItem -Path $ServerHomeDirShare -Directory | 
    Where-Object { $users -notcontains ($_.Name -replace '^(\w+\.\w+).*', '$1') } |
    Select-Object -Property Name, FullName,
                  @{ n = 'LastAccessTime'; e = { $_.LastAccessTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') } },
                  @{ n = "Directory Size (MB)"; e = {
                            Try {
                                $Size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
                                         Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB
                                [math]::Round($Size, 2)
                            }
                            Catch {
                                "ERROR: $($_.Exception.Message)"
                            }
                        }
                    } |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\UserProfilesNotExist-Size.csv
```

However, there is one more issue that needed fixing, to add **DOMAIN\Domain Admins** AD group as Full Access to the directory ACL, *BUT ONLY when the directory is not accessible or throwing error.*

```
    $FullAccessADGroup = "DOMAIN\Domain Admins"
    
    function Take-Ownership
    {
        param (
            [String]$Folder
        )
        takeown.exe /A /F $Folder
        $CurrentACL = Get-Acl $Folder
        
        write-host "`n`t...Adding NT Authority\SYSTEM to $Folder" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $SystemACLPermission = "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
        $SystemAccessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $SystemACLPermission
        $CurrentACL.AddAccessRule($SystemAccessRule)
        
        write-host "`t...Adding Infrastructure Services to $Folder" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $AdminACLPermission = $FullAccessADGroup, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
        $SystemAccessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $AdminACLPermission
        $CurrentACL.AddAccessRule($SystemAccessRule)
        
        Set-Acl -Path $Folder -AclObject $CurrentACL
    }
    
function Test-Folder($FolderToTest) {
    $error.Clear()
    $ErrorArray = @()
    Get-ChildItem $FolderToTest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName
    if ($error) {
        $ErrorArray = $error + $ErrorArray
        foreach ($err in $ErrorArray) {
            if ($err.FullyQualifiedErrorId -eq "DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand") {
                Write-Host Unable to access $err.TargetObject -ForegroundColor Red
                Write-Host Attempting to take ownership of $err.TargetObject -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Take-Ownership($err.TargetObject)
                Test-Folder($err.TargetObject)
            }
        }
    }
}

Test-Folder $source
```

Because even though I am using DOMAIN\Administrator account to execute the script above, I cannot get the directory size or even opened the directory via the UNCPath, this is the error:

```
ERROR: Access to the path '\\FileServer\HomeDir$\Jane.Liz.V2' is denied.
ERROR: Access to the path '\\FileServer\HomeDir$\Lisa.Chan.V5' is denied.
ERROR: Access to the path '\\FileServer\HomeDir$\Carolline.Marce.V6' is denied.
...
```

Comment: Isn't the local group "Administrators" part of the ACL? And on a domain joined computer "DOMAIN\Domain Admins" is a member of "Administrators". So probably your problem is already solved. At least on default.

Comment: What kind of problem are you having? I ran the second portion of code above and it worked first try.  All I did was use my own domain name and point it to a local folder.  Looked back at the ACL and domain admins was there with full access...

Comment: I got this error: ERROR: Access to the path '\\FileServer\HomeDir$\Jane.Liz.V2' is denied.
Since the directory is not accessible or browseable.
The account I am using is DOMAIN\Administrator but still I cannot see the content of that user profile?

Comment: From what I understand you're trying to access the folder via sharing. Sharing permissions are different from NTFS permissions. Have you checked how the sharing permissions are?

Comment: Yes I have checked it is not related to Shared folder Permmission.
ERROR: Access to the path '\\FileServer\RoamingProfiles\UserData$\Stevanie.Angel.V6' is denied.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.